# Converging series of functions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I don't know even how to think about it:

Let $f$ be defined in the interval $[-1, 1]$. Assume $f(0)=0$, its derivative is continuous in $(-1,1)$ and $f'(0)=\beta \neq 0$. Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f^2({1\over \sqrt{n}})$ diverges and  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f^2({1\over n})$ converges.

Hint: Use the limit comparison test (specifically, compare with the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ .

Comment: Hint: what does the graph of $f$ look like near $\{0,f(0)\}$.

Comment: Does $f^2(\cdot)$ denote $f(f(\cdot))$ or $[f(\cdot)]^2$?

Comment: $f^2(\cdot)$ denotes $[f(\cdot)]^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, remember that

$$\forall a\in (0,1) \exists c\in (0,a) : f(a)=f(a)-f(0)=f'(c)(a-0)=f'(c)a,$$ from where

$$\forall a\in (0,1) \exists c\in (0,a) : f^2(a)=(f'(c))^2a^2.$$

Assume wlog that $\beta>0.$ Now, since $f'$ is continuous at $0:$

$$\exists \delta>0 : |x|<\delta \implies |f'(x)-\beta|=|f'(x)-f'(0)|<\frac{\beta}{2},$$ from where

$$|x|<\delta \implies \frac{\beta}{2}=f'(x)<\frac{3\beta}{2}.$$

Thus, for $n$ big enough ($1/n<\delta$) it is

$$f^2(1/n)=(f'(c_n))^2\frac1{n^2}\le \frac{9\beta^2}{4n^{2}}$$

and ($1/\sqrt{n}<\delta$)

$$f^2(1/\sqrt{n})=(f'(c_n))^2\frac1n\ge \frac{\beta^2}{4n}.$$

From this, we can conclude what you want to show.

Comment: couldn't understand how the last line was created: $$f^2(1/\sqrt{n})=(f'(c_n))^2\frac1n\ge \frac{\beta^2}{4n}.$$ --- wasn't suppose to be: $$f^2(1/\sqrt{n})=(f'(c_n))^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$ ?? and how the part after $\geq$ also not clear.
on top of all - how does this help , me ? waht do i know about $$\frac{\beta^2}{4n}$$ or $$\frac{9\beta^2}{4n}$$

Comment: I have edited to fix typos in line 4 from the bottom.

Comment: Still, line 5 does not make sense... how did you conclude that $$f^2(1/\sqrt{n})=(f'(c_n))^2\frac1n\ge \frac{\beta^2}{4n}.$$  It seems much more like it should be: $$f^2(1/\sqrt{n})=(f'(c_n))^2\frac1n\le \frac{9\beta^2}{4n}.$$

Comment: Note that $\beta/2<f'(c_n)<3\beta/2$ implies $\beta^2/4<(f'(c_n))^2.$ Thus $$f^2(1/\sqrt{n})=(f'(c_n))^2\left(\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right)^2\ge \frac{\beta^2}{4n}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Since your function is continuously differentiable, then by the Taylor expansion, for $x$ sufficiently near $0$, you have
$$ f(x)=\beta x+\mathcal{O}(x^2)$$
and
$$ f^2(x)=\beta^2 x^2+\mathcal{O}(x^3)$$
leading to
$$f^2({1\over \sqrt{n}})\sim \beta \frac1n+\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n^2})$$
and 
$$f^2({1\over n})\sim \beta^2 \frac{1}{n^2}+\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n^3}).$$
Consequently, $\sum f^2({1\over \sqrt{n}})$ is divergent and $\sum f^2({1\over n})$ is convergent.